# Converting pixels to dpi for mdpi and hdpi screens

Tags: java, android, dpi, floating-accuracy

I am using this code that I have found on another thread which is working fine on mdpi screens:

```
public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp,Context context){
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi/160f);
        return px;
    }

public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px,Context context){
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        float dp = px / (metrics.densityDpi /160f);
        return dp;

    }
```

When using it on hdpi screens the text size jumps when trying to increase the text size. I am assuming its because it is using the hardcoded 160f when dividing the densityDpi? Is there any dynamic way to determine whether it is 160dpi or 240dpi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method:

```
public float dpToPx(float dp, Context context) {
    float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return dp * density;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html):

```
metrics.density
```

is the scaling factor you are looking for.

> This is a scaling factor for the Density Independent Pixel unit, where one DIP is one pixel on an approximately 160 dpi screen (for example a 240x320, 1.5"x2" screen), providing the baseline of the system's display. Thus on a 160dpi screen this density value will be 1; on a 120 dpi screen it would be .75; etc.