# Strange behavior of setTextSize (or maybe something else!)

Tags: android

I want to set the text size of my TextView to be proportional to screen width. I'm getting screen width using this code:

```
public static int getScreenWidth(Context context) {
    if (SCREEN_WIDTH == 0) {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getMetrics(outMetrics);
        SCREEN_WIDTH = outMetrics.widthPixels;
    }
    return SCREEN_WIDTH;
}
```

When I set the font size to be a proportion of screen width

```
textView.setTextSize(screenWidth / something);
```

I get different results on different devices, particularly Samsung GT-I9000 (android 2.3.3) and Nexus 7 (android 4.3).

However I managed to get it right by doing it this way:

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                Utils.pixelsToDip(context, screenWidth / something));
```

It's weird because basically it's like multiplying and dividing by same value.

Here is pixelsToDip method:

```
public static float pixelsToDip(Context context, float px) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float dp = px / (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return dp;
}
```

Does anyone knows what is the problem here? Maybe there is some faults in pixelToDip method, or I have a misunderstanding of size units?

Comment: what's the problem with using sp units?

Comment: no it doesn't look the same in different devices with sp unit.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751080/converting-pixels-to-dpi-for-mdpi-and-hdpi-screens?rq=1) can help you.

Comment: I want to know why the first method I've specified doesn't work. As I said I've handled the problem with a weird method.